# Trouble formatting first exercise from Practical Common LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

I'm beginning to work through Practical Common LISP and the first exercise is to write a [simple database](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html). I'm using GNU CLISP 2.48 (2009-07-28) on cygwin.

This code, which I've compared against the book several times, doesn't produce output the way the book says it should

```
(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped))
(defvar *db* nil)
(defun add-record (cd) (push cd *db*))
(add-record (make-cd "Roses" "Kathy Mattea" 7 t))
(add-record (make-cd "Fly" "Dixie Chicks" 8 t))
(add-record (make-cd "Home" "Dixie Chicks" 9 t))
(defun dump-db ()
  (dolist (cd *db*)
   (format t "~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%" cd)))

(dump-db)
```

I get

```
TITLE:    Home
ARTIST:   Dixie Chicks
RATING:   9
RIPPED:   
*** - There are not enough arguments left for this format directive.
      Current point in control string:
        "~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%"
                  |
```

I don't understand `format` or LISP well enough to being to troubleshoot. The book says I should be getting a list of all the records in the database. What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's look at the return from (make-cd):

```
[12]> (make-cd "Home" "Dixie Chicks" 9 t)
(:TITLE "Home" :ARTIST "Dixie Chicks" :RATING 9 :RIPPED)
```

You aren't including a value for `:ripped`! Change (make-cd) to:

```
(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))
```

Note the `ripped` after `:ripped`.

Comment: Ugh, how silly of me! I spent 15 minutes cross-checking that format string.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the compiler in CLISP, it tells you what is wrong:

```
[1]> (defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
       (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped))   
MAKE-CD

[2]> (compile 'make-cd)
WARNING: in MAKE-CD : variable RIPPED is not used.
         Misspelled or missing IGNORE declaration?
MAKE-CD ;
1 ;
NIL
```

The variable `RIPPED` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

The format directive `~{...~}` is an iterative construct, and its corresponding argument is expected to be a list.  Furthermore in this case, because of the two occurrences of `~a`, each iteration will consume two items, so the total number of items in the list is expected to be even.  Yet you provided it with an odd number of items.